# How to open the Windows 8.1 Settings from my XAML app event or command instead of the charm?

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1

I would like to have a simple button that would open the Windows 8.1 settings flyout just like the Windows 8.1 settings charm does.  Is this possible from my 8.1 XAML app using an event or a command?

Answer (score 0):

You can place this in yout Button_click-event:

```
   FlyoutSettings flyoutsettings= new FlyoutSettings();
   flyoutsettings.Show();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Cool idea, but unfortunately, it didn't work.  Note: I changed FlyoutSettings to SettingsFlyout.

Comment: Did you already read that one? [Add app settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh872190.aspx)    If you called your settings 'CustomSettings' like in that example you would have to use the above code like that: CustomSettings flyoutsettings = new CustomSettings(); ...

Comment: My settings flyouts that inherit from the SettingsFlyout class work fine.  However, I'm trying to get that Windows 8 flyout that is in the OS to show up.  The blue one with the links to the my settings flyouts.

Comment: Oh sorry, now i know what you want. I think the easiest way to achieve that is to send keys: windows + C; with SendKeys()